# How to Auto Logon in Webbrowser with Windows Login credentials

Tags: windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a website (internal application) which requires a username and password which is the same as their windows login credentials. Single sign on is technically not possible. I have about 1000 clients which need to enter their account details every time so I would like to automate this. Is it possible to script something where the user clicks on a shortcut on their desktop and is automatically logged in with the windows credentials on the website? Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is hosted on the IIS server for internal use than you can try to refer example below may help you to solve your issue.

Code:

```
// Ensure Directory Security settings for default web site in IIS is "Windows Authentication".
string url = "http://localhost";
// Create a 'HttpWebRequest' object with the specified url. 
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
// Assign the credentials of the logged in user or the user being impersonated.
myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
// Send the 'HttpWebRequest' and wait for response.            
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(); 
Console.WriteLine("Authentication successful");
Console.WriteLine("Response received successfully");
```

DefaultCredentials represents the system credentials for the current security context in which the application is running. For a client-side application, these are usually the Windows credentials (user name, password, and domain) of the user running the application. For ASP.NET applications, the default credentials are the user credentials of the logged-in user, or the user being impersonated.

Reference:

[CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials?view=netframework-4.7.2)